# onclick innerhtml does not work - not common issue

Tags: javascript, html, debugging

What could be potentially wrong with the following simple code:

```html
<span onclick="this.innerHTML='123456'; return false;">XXXXXX <strong>Show it!</strong></span>
```

The problem exists for few users, but I do not have physical access to the machines to debug it. When they click on it nothing happens.
I cannot replicate it, it works fine everywhere where I have physical access (even tried BrowserStack) and I'm running out of ideas.
Yes, they have JS up and running.
Different users, different browsers.
Asked them to try on JSFiddle as well - same issue.

Buggy version of web browser? Other software/addon blocks it?

Any ideas? Anybody had or have the same issue?

Thx in advance.

Comment: You're asking us to debug code...that works?

Comment: Why are you using a redundant return statement (not a criticism, just wondering)?

Comment: Ask them to check their browser console for error messages.

Comment: @j08691 He's asking for ideas of how to troubleshoot when the program works for him but not for some users.

Comment: Have you tried removing the return false? Or return true instead?

Comment: @Saskia I can't see how that could matter. `return false;` prevents the default action of clicking on the element, but DIVs don't have a default click action.

Comment: Probably they have some old browsers and some other fancy new*ish* JS from your side causes errors. Review your complete JS cause the above is not your issue.

Comment: Does other Javascript on your site work for them? Maybe they have Javascript disabled. Add a `<noscript>` tag that warns them that your site requires JS.

Comment: i imagine "123456" is not the actual display value you want. are you by any chance populating that from the server? is it possible that the real value could contain a single or double quote? cus that would break it. i would try stripping quotes from the real string.

Comment: quotes would break for every browser, this is only for some browsers. Some browsers are insane, I have written much code for browsers and I know some of them react differently on return true or false in an onclick event.

Comment: if some of them didn;t have quotes  and he only tested ones without quotes my answer would explain the problem.

Comment: this is super basic javascript that should work on every js enabled browser. human error is most likely in this case.

Comment: What is the actual content that you are setting `innerHTML` to? Is it plain text, or is it HTML? Can you give a concrete example where you know it does not work? Or does it really not work for those users, even with `123456` as in your example?

Comment: @j08691 - yes, I know that sounds stupid, code works, and have no idea what could cause it, but I'm hopping that someone in this community aproached it before, and knows the reason

Comment: @Saskia - had it earlier without it, and add it cause someone suggested about different case that it's better to have it there

Comment: @Barmar - have it on my website, and they claim that it does not show up, so that is unfortunately not an issue, as I mentioned even JSFiddle does not work for them

Comment: @trincot - it's plain text, phone number actually, id does not work even with that simple example which I provided to them on JSFiddle to test: https://jsfiddle.net/b80azp8h/

Comment: Well the only reason to have a return false over there, is when this onclick parameter is inside an A tag, in order to stop further execution (execute HREF). No need to put it in here. But seriously though, have you let these people try it without the return false? It may seriously help. Also: Ask them exactly what browser they have and what version. Only then you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: NB: Removing `return false` will not help, as by that time the `innerHTML` should already have changed.

Comment: You could let your users test this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b80azp8h/1/. It should alert something useful, and maybe it even works like this.

Comment: @trincot - will do, thx